# Filling a matrix efficiently in R based on row and column indices

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I am filling a matrix in R, and the most(?) intuitive way to do this is to use two nested loops: one for rows and one for columns. However, this method tends to be quite slow, and the use of apply() function is usually preferable.

Everything would be easy with apply, if I was just transforming the existing values of my matrix with some function, but I am actually using an external function which takes the row and column indices as arguments and returns a value.

The function could be something like this (just an example):

```
myfunction <- function(rownumber, colnumber) {
                       if(rownumber + colnumber < 7) {
                          return(4)
                       } else {
                          return(2)
                       }
}
```

...and with two nested loops we could proceed like this:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

for(rownum in 1:nrow(m)) {
    for(colnum in 1:ncol(m)) {
        m[rownum, colnum] <- myfunction(rownum, colnum)
    }
}
```

And something like this comes out:

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    4    4    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4    4    2
[3,]    4    4    4    2    2
[4,]    4    4    2    2    2
[5,]    4    2    2    2    2
```

I would like to use apply() function for this, since it is generally faster than two nested loops, but I have no idea, how to get row number and column number - or if that's even possible? One solution would be to save the row numbers and col numbers initially to the matrix as STRINGS, but again this would take some time, since it needs to be done with two nested loops...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: First, `apply` is a wrapper of `R's` for loop and is NOT generally faster than for-loop. Actually, it might be slower depending on the overheads. You rather use plain for loops, or you transform your function in a way that is vectorized. The issue does not lie with the for-loop but rather with your current function. Once that is vectorized, then you can ignore the for loop completely. Try not to vectorize your function using `Vectorize` function, but rather dive deep and see whether there is anything you can do. Otherwise, use`lapply`-its code is in `C`

Comment: Check out the function `outer`, I believe it is what you need.

Comment: see `row()`, `column()`, and indexing/setting matrices using a two-column [i,j] matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

outer should accomplish what you need

First, make sure your function can work vectorized:

```
myfunction <- function(rownumber, colnumber) {
     ifelse(rownumber + colnumber < 7,4,2) # ifelse is vectorized
 }
```

Then

```
outer(0:5, 0:5, FUN = myfunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function is efficiently vectorized, you can do a matrix of row indices and a matrix of column indices as follows:

```r
rownumbers <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    2    2    2
# [3,]    3    3    3
# [4,]    4    4    4
colnumbers <- t(matrix(1:4, nrow = 4, ncol = 4))[, 1:3]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
# [3,]    1    2    3
# [4,]    1    2    3
```

Then do `f(rownumbers, colnumbers)`.

---

## EDIT

I've just discovered the functions `col` and `row`. It's easier to use these functions to construct the two matrices.